# jquery script don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {

      $('#navmenu').css('position', 'fixed');
      $('#navmenu').css('background', 'black');
      $('#navmenu').css('width', '100%');
      $('#navmenu').css('margin-left', '0%');
      $('#navmenu').css('opacity', '0.9');
      $('#navmenu').css('height', '35%');
      $('#navmenu').css('margin-top', '2.2%');


    } else {
        $('#navmenu').css('position', 'relative');
        $('#navmenu').css('background', 'transparent');
        $('#navmenu').css('opacity', '1');
        $('#navmenu').css('margin-top', '0px');   
   }

} );
```

and here you can see my problem. [PROBLEM](http://stefanvblog.com/palestinski-informaticar-ukazao-na-propust-na-facebooku/)
Script works great on big post but on small post i have that bug. how to fix that..

Comment: "Does not work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: This code shows you exactly how to do things very inefficiently. Set a class!  `$('#navmenu').toggleClass("fixedMenu", $(window).scrollTop() > 20);` and set up rules.

Comment: You can see my problem on the link.. when i try to scroll it is just blink.. and ok, i set a class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to show you first that `.css()` can be used like

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
          $('#navmenu').css({
          'position', 'fixed',  //change to absolute
          'background', 'black',
          'width', '100%',
          'margin-left', '0%',
          'opacity', '0.9',
          'height', '35%',
          'margin-top', '2.2%'
        });
    }   else {
        $('#navmenu').css({'position', 'relative',
            'background', 'transparent',
            'opacity', '1',
            'margin-top', '0px'
       });
   }
});
```

The problem is here in setting **`position`**

remove `'position', 'fixed'` or use **`absolute`** positioning.

> [**`fixed`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and **doesn't move when scrolled**. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page.

*Whenever you scroll, it is setting the position fixed and therefore the blink occurs.*